# I am encountering an issue in my React PDF project where I am unable to visualize the bottom and right margins as well as the borders of my reactPDF

Tags: css, reactjs, border, margin, react-pdf

I'm trying to generate a PDF using the @react-pdf/renderer library in my React application. Everything seems to be working fine except for one issue: the right and bottom margins are not visible in the generated PDF. However, the top and left margins are clearly visible.

here's my code

```js
import React from 'react'
import Title from './components/Title'
import { PDFViewer, Page, Document, View } from '@react-pdf/renderer'
import Table from './components/Table'
import Footer from './components/Footer'

const App = () => {
  const tableData = [

    { sno: 2, hsn: 67890, mfg: 'XYZ Corp.' },
    { sno: 2, hsn: 67890, mfg: 'XYZ Corp.' },
  ]
  return (
    <PDFViewer style={{ width: '100%', height: '100vh' }}>
      <Document>
        <Page
          orientation="landscape"
          size="A4"
          style={{
            border: 1,
            margin: 20,
          }}
        >
          <View style={{ border: '1px solid black' }}>
            <Title />
            <Table tableData={tableData} />
            <Footer />
          </View>
        </Page>
      </Document>
    </PDFViewer>
  )
}

export default App
```

[image: As you can see margin right and bottom are not visible]

Comment: Please share a link of codesandbox, So we can also look your Table component and debug the issue.

Comment: @MaulikPatel  https://codesandbox.io/p/github/varunteja01/reactpdflandscape/main

never used codesandbox tried it for the first time hope that link helps

Comment: I have added solutions below, go through it and let me know - If you have any questions.

Comment: @MaulikPatel thank you very much! it helped me

Comment: Mark that answer as accepted, if that was resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have applied margin on all the sides this way:

> **Note:** I am not able to paste link because your link was private, I have pasted part of the code which you need to change as below.

**Step1: You need to add styles this way:**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "#E4E4E4",
  },
  section: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
});
```

**Step2: Apply styles in the View**

```
<Page orientation="landscape" size="A4" style={styles.page}>
  <View style={styles.section}>
    <Title />
    <Table tableData={tableData} />
    <Footer />
  </View>
</Page>;
```

Let me know, if you've any further questions.